# Angular 2 Validate form on Submit

Tags: angular

Hi How do I validate my angular form on submit button clicked without 
formbuilder or formGroup or disabling the submit button as I want to let the user know what data is missing.

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
                    <header>
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Register
                    </header>  
                    <fieldset class="nomargin">    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">                                        
                                <div class="col-sm-12" [class.has-error]="username.touched && username.invalid">                                                                                                        
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.username' class="form-control"  #username="ngModel" name="username" type="text"autofocus="" required="true"  placeholder="Username" >
                                    <i class="ico-append fa fa-user right-25"></i>

                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid">
                                        username is required
                                    </div>                            
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Needed to identify you during login</b>                                
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">                                        
                                <div class="col-sm-12" [class.has-error]="password.touched && password.invalid">                                                                                                                                         
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.password' class="form-control"  #password="ngModel" name="password" type="password" pattern='^....+' required="true" placeholder="Password">
                                    <i class="ico-append fa fa-lock  right-25"></i>
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid">
                                        Password must be atleast 4 characters long 
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf='password.touched && registration.password==""'>
                                        Please enter a password 
                                    </div>  
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Only characters and numbers</b>                                    
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">                                        
                                <div class="col-sm-12 " [class.has-error]="validateConfirmPassword(confirmPassword.touched)">                                                                                                                                       
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.confirmPassword'                                           
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        #confirmPassword="ngModel" 
                                        name="confirmPassword" 
                                        type="password"  
                                        required="true" 
                                        placeholder="Confirm password">
                                    <i class="ico-append fa fa-lock  right-25"></i>                                    
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="registration.confirmPassword!=registration.password && confirmPassword.touched">
                                        Does not match password 
                                    </div>      
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Only characters and numbers</b>                       
                                </div>                                                  
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">                                        
                                <div class="col-sm-12 " [class.has-error]="emailAddress.touched && emailAddress.invalid">                                                                                                                                        
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.emailAddress' class="form-control" #emailAddress="ngModel" name="emailAddress" type="text" required="true"  placeholder="Email address">
                                    <i class="ico-append fa fa-envelope  right-25"></i>
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="emailAddress.touched && emailAddress.invalid">
                                        Email address is required
                                    </div>   
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Needed to verify your account</b>                       
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">                                        
                                <div class="col-sm-6 " [class.has-error]="firstName.touched && firstName.invalid">                                                                                                                                                                         
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.firstName' class="form-control" #firstName="ngModel" name="firstName" type="text" required="true"  placeholder="First name">
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="firstName.touched && firstName.invalid">
                                        First Name is required
                                    </div>                                                                                      
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="col-sm-6" [class.has-error]="lastName.touched && lastName.invalid">                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.lastName' class="form-control" #lastName="ngModel" name="lastName" type="text" required="true"  placeholder="Last name">
                                    <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="lastName.touched && lastName.invalid">
                                        Last Name is required
                                    </div>                                                                                       
                                </div>                 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="select margin-bottom-10 margin-top-20">
                            <div  class="form-group" [class.has-error]='gender.touched && registration.gender=="default"'> 
                                <select [(ngModel)]='registration.gender' class="form-control" #gender="ngModel" name="gender" >
                                    <option value="default" default disabled>Gender</option>
                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class='alert-danger' *ngIf='gender.touched && registration.gender=="default"'>
                                    Please select a Gender
                                </div>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="margin-top-30">
                            <div class="nomargin" >                            
                                <label class="checkbox nomargin has-error">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]='registration.acceptTerms'
                                        (change)="validateTerms(!acceptTerms.value)" 
                                        class="checked-agree" 
                                        #acceptTerms="ngModel" 
                                        name="acceptTerms" 
                                        required="true" 
                                        type="checkbox">
                                    <i [class.checkbox-error]="displayTermsValidaionError" ></i>
                                    I agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Terms of Service</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>                        
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="register()" ><i class="fa fa-check"></i> REGISTER</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    {{result.messageResult}}
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form.submitted` property indicates whether the form is submitted or not. Can be used in template as:

```
<div class='alert-danger' *ngIf="form.submitted && username.invalid">
     username is required
</div>
```

Comment: The Angular way to listen to the form submission event is `<form (ngSubmit)="register()">`.

Comment: In fact, the first part of your answer is really unnecessary. If you put `(submit)` on form or `button type="submit" (click)=".."` - as he did -... makes no difference at all. But the second part of your answer is that the OP is looking for.

Comment: Right, didn't notice `type="submit"` part. Will update the answer. Thx

Comment: Thank you. I should have given it more thought. in the end I changed it to {[class.has-error]="(username.touched||form.submitted) && username.invalid"}